# JQuery not removing class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

So, I am trying to create blocks that cycle through some colors. Each color is defined by a class, and I remove a certain class color, then add another class color when a block is clicked. Each segment of code looks like this:

```
//Function 1
$('.blue').click(function(){
    console.log("Blue has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $(this).removeClass('blue');
}); 

//Function 2
$('.green').click(function(){
    console.log("Green has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('yellow');
    $(this).removeClass('green');
});
```

When a block is clicked a first time, the color is changed. But when I click it again, the color does not change.

I added `console.log` statements to monitor in Console what was happening. As an example, when I click a box that has the `blue` class, it adds the `green` class, and the `blue` class is removed. But when I click the same box (that is now green) I expect the second function to run, and the box to change into a yellow color. However, what I can see through the console is that the first function is trying to run again.

I checked the HTML, and the classes do change.

My question is, why is function 1 triggered when the first box is no longer a member of the `blue` class? Should it not be calling function 2, since it is now a member of the `green` class?

The CodePen is [here](http://codepen.io/SammyIsra/pen/zxeZpm), I am actively working on it. I will mention here when the CodePen works.

**The CodePen now works, I used `$(document).on('click', '.green')` instead of `$('.green).click()` **

Thank you!

Comment: just bind your click with parent class or document then it will work.

Comment: `$('.green').click` is your issue.. you need the event to be handled by the document.. or as Sumit said, a parent element.

Comment: toggleClass like `$(this).toggleClass('green blue');` seems to be a better practice here

Comment: That toggle will only switch from green to blue.  OP wants all blocks to cycle through all 4 colors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to change the event handlers based on changed selectors you need to use event delegation.

```
//Function 1
$(document).on('click', '.blue', function () {
    console.log("Blue has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $(this).removeClass('blue');
});

//Function 2
$(document).on('click', '.green', function () {
    console.log("Green has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('yellow');
    $(this).removeClass('green');
});
```

In your event registration, the selectors are evaluated only once when the page is loaded, any changes done after that to the classes will not affect the registered handlers.

---

### Code Snippet Example

```js
$(document).on('click', '.blue', function () {
    console.log("Blue has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $(this).removeClass('blue');
});

//Function 2
$(document).on('click', '.green', function () {
    console.log("Green has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('yellow');
    $(this).removeClass('green');
});

$(document).on('click', '.yellow', function () {
    console.log("Yellow has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('blue');
    $(this).removeClass('yellow');
});

$(document).on('click', '.red', function () {
    console.log("Red has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('blue');
    $(this).removeClass('red');
});
```

```css
.block{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.green{
 background-color: green;
}

.blue{
 background-color: blue;
} 

.yellow{
 background-color: yellow;
}

.red{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block green'></div>
<div class='block blue'></div>
<div class='block yellow'></div>
<div class='block red'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `on` instead of `click`, because you're changing the class of your div, so you have to use `.on()` to get the click event bind when it changes the class

```
//Function 1
$(document).on('click', '.blue', function(){
    console.log("Blue has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('green');
    $(this).removeClass('blue');
}); 

//Function 2
$(document).on('click', '.green', function(){
    console.log("Green has been clicked");
    $(this).addClass('yellow');
    $(this).removeClass('green');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qksr7q3c/)

Comment: should maybe add that you need to use $(document).on instead of targeting the specific classes at run time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is this: http://jsfiddle.net/drxzLqrL/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    function foo($elm){
        var color = $elm.data('color');
        switch (color) {
            case 'blue':
                $elm.addClass('green')
                    .removeClass('blue')
                    .data('color', 'green');
                break;
            case 'green':
                $elm.addClass('yellow')
                        .removeClass('green')
                        .data('color', 'yellow');
                break;
            case 'yellow':
                $elm.addClass('red')
                    .removeClass('yellow')
                    .data('color', 'red');
                break;
            case 'red':
                $elm.addClass('blue')
                    .removeClass('red')
                    .data('color', 'blue');
        }
    }
    $('.block').on('click', function(e){
        foo($(e.currentTarget));
    }); 
});
```

Also use `.on()` instead of `.click()`, because you have to get the event when it changes the class and `.on()` provide you all the functionality of both .bind() and .live()

I hope it's help! :)

Comment: `switch(undefined)`.. why are you presuming he is using data attributes? and this code is considered bad practice because it is checking it's own elements state.. which is what the classes are declared for..

Comment: @BrettCaswell I'm using data in my example thats why I'm using it. I have done some changes to separare the function logic from the element. Thanks!

Comment: I promote the usage of data attributes, but it doesn't change the fact that this code will only error.. because you aren't handling `$elm.data('color') == undefined` .. which it will be in the OP's case and anyone who doesn't have `data-color=""` existing and defined to one of those 4 values.. it's a simple matter to correct though.. `var color = $elm.data('color') || "red";` but now you're defining a default state for a block .. which wasn't expressed as an intention.. so it needs to be regarded as a altered behavior..

Answer (score 0):

You want to use jQuery's .on() instead of the basic event binding:
https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: did you read the comments before providing this answer?.. the issue isn't the method that registered the event handling

Comment: although, to be fair.. if you meant the event-delegate form of using `.on()` then as a one-liner you would be correct :P.. but it still doesn't really address or answer the OP's question regarding why function 1 executes when he expects it to execute function 2, right ?

Comment: Of course, you are right, Brett - this was just a little bit too short of an answer. It was my intention to get get the OP on the right track but should have explained this a little more. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `toggleClass` in this case.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mkgg7t9L/)

Comment: I +1, because this demonstrates that the events are still firing.. and no one mentioned that as of yet.. but toggling between two states (i.e. classes) doesn't apply to the desired functionality..

Answer (score 0):

These clicks are binded to the elements only once, so they will not be there when you change the class.  Instead, bind the click event to the 'block' class.  You might also want to write this a bit more efficiently with switches or if/else.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.block').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('blue'))
        {                   
            $(this).addClass('green').removeClass('blue');
        }
    else if($(this).hasClass('green'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('yellow').removeClass('green');
        }
    else if($(this).hasClass('yellow'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('red').removeClass('yellow');
        }
    else if($(this).hasClass('red'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('blue').removeClass('red');
        }

    $('.block').click(function(){
        console.log("Block has been clicked");
    });
 });
});
```

You can view it working here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvGPyx

Comment: no, that's incorrect.. they are not bound and handled once.. the elements that were initially bound will continue to raise and execute the same handler function regardless of their class name removal.. but the handler function will execute the same everytime.. It's just that the function itself is idempotent..that is.. removing the same class from itself (which does not effect), adding the same class to itself.. (which - it would seem - does not effect... because the method **addClass** disregards adding the same class over and over)

Answer (score 0):

Lets do something different here. we'll use `bind` on the function - prior to executing it - to pass in an object parameter, and the scope of the function (`this`) being the instance handled within the anonymous function, or event delegate handler.

```js
//Common Function
function ChangeState(state, evArg)
{
  console.clear();
  console.log("this: %o, state: %o, evArg: %o", this, state, evArg);
  $(this).addClass(state.new);
  $(this).removeClass(state.old);
}

//Function 1

$(document).on("click", ".blue", function(evArg){
  ChangeState.bind(this,{"old":"blue","new":"yellow"}, evArg)();
});


$(document).on("click", ".yellow", function(evArg){
  ChangeState.bind(this,{"old":"yellow","new":"red"}, evArg)();
});

$(document).on("click", ".red", function(evArg){
  ChangeState.bind(this,{"old":"red","new":"green"}, evArg)();
});


$(document).on("click", ".green", function(evArg){
  ChangeState.bind(this,{"old":"green","new":"blue"}, evArg)();
});
```

```css
.block{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.green{
 background-color: green;
}

.blue{
 background-color: blue;
} 

.yellow{
 background-color: yellow;
}

.red{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block green'></div>
<div class='block blue'></div>
<div class='block yellow'></div>
<div class='block red'></div>
```

Comment: what's important to note here is that if I try to assign ChangeState to be the event handler, then the instance (this) will be the `window`... that is, generally.. you could do this `$(".blue").on("click", ChangeState.bind(null,{"old":"blue","new":"yellow"}));` .. but, again, it won't be **live**.. so it will behave like the OP's initial implementation.. furthermore, it doesn't function properly in an event-delegate implementation.. the reason isn't particular obvious.. you're essentially forced to use an anonymous function